# Can I Grant a User Permission to Edit a Firestore Collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a PWA (Web-App) and would like my client to be able to enter data such as new events into the Cloud Firestore, without me having to create a UI (ie. using the Firebase Console with permissions to only edit a collection).

It would also be alright to just grant permission to the whole Firestore for this user (as it's his data). I'm thinking of something like phpMyAdmin.

Would the user need a gmail-Account? I found something in the Project Settings (Users and Permissions - IAM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible in the Firebase or Google Cloud console. A user either has edit permission on Firestore as a whole, or they don't.

The console is focused on developers, and not a great fit for the type of use-case you're describing. The most common approach to such a use-case is to write a custom admin app for these users. If you don't feel like that, look at some of the existing [admin panels](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+admin+panel) or [content management systems](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+CMS) that build on top of Firebase out there.